# How to create a file (testfile.txt) in python 3 Jupyter note Book 6.0.3 in windows 7

Tags: python

How to create a file (testfile.txt) in python 3 Jupyter note Book 6.0.3 in windows 7?
I'm working through Anaconda

```
file1 = open("testfile.txt", "r")
```

```
FileNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test file.txt'
```

Comment: `open(..., 'r')` will open an existing file for reading - that's what the R stands for. Are you aware of that? BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice.

Answer (score 1):

The 'r' argument stands for read mode that's why there is a complain about missing file. You should create it by opening in write mode 'w'

```
file1 = open("testfile.txt", "w")
```